# Does for an operator on an Hilbert space symmetric, densley defined and bijective imply self adjoint?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

I have an operator $L \colon D(L) \subset H \to H$, where $H$ is an Hilbert space and $D(L)$ is a dense subset of $H$.
If $L$ is now symmetric and bijective, is it then automatically self-adjoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Symmetry implies $L \preceq L^*$ (graph inclusion.) To show that $L^*\preceq L$, suppose $x \in \mathcal{D}(L^*)$. Then there exists $y\in \mathcal{D}(L)$ such that $Ly=L^*x$ because $L$ is surjective. Then, for all $z\in\mathcal{D}(L)$,
$$
    \langle x,Lz\rangle= \langle L^*x, z \rangle = \langle Ly,z\rangle=\langle y,Lz\rangle.
$$
Because $L$ is surjective, then $x=y$, which means an arbitrary $x\in\mathcal{D}(L^*)$ is in $\mathcal{D}(L)$.

Comment: Ah, nice argument! Do you mean "injective" in the last line?

Comment: @Luke Using surjectivity, we can infer from $\langle x,Lz\rangle=\langle y,Lz\rangle$ for all $z\in\mathcal{D}(L)$ that $\langle x,w\rangle=\langle y,w\rangle$ for all $w\in H$.

Comment: Now I got it, thanks!

Comment: @Luke : Note, you do not need to assume $L$ is injective. Surjectivity is enough.